# Passing initializing variables in my reactjs application

Tags: reactjs, npm

I have a reactjs application which I start through command line by 'npm start' and it uses react-script start to run the project.

In my project, I use to send requests to a REST-API service, but I need to have a host address and port for this which it should be fed from my react application. Can someone point me how to do this in reactjs and npm applications?

Comment: Do you want to fetch/post something from the API service?

Comment: I am using axios post in my application which I shoud give them the host address and port number of my REST-API application..